# Combining xml documents using xslt to make valid html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm having some trouble combining multiple xml documents to make a valid html document, my main issue is with the correct point to disable the escaping in my source xml document(s). I am using code like the following in my xslt:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('../xml/mydocument.xml')"/>
```

This works fine when the content of mydocument.xml is escaped, so & is present as `&amp`; for example. However, I want un-escape these characters for my final html document and I can't seem to get it to work.

If I un-escape the characters in the source xml document then I make the xml invalid and therefore can't copy it into the main document.

Does anyone have any advice for how to do this? Should I be combining multiple source html documents instead (note that the source documents are themselves the product of a transform)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my main issue is with the correct point to disable the escaping in my
>   source xml document(s).

The correct point to disable output escaping is when you are outputting a text node to the result tree (and not before).

Note that only the `xsl:text` and `xsl:value-of` elements are allowed to have a `disable-output-escaping` attribute; you cannot *copy* nodes and disable output escaping at the same time. You need to *process* the nodes specifically by applying templates or xsl:for-each.

---

### Edit:

For example, given the following **input**:

```
<p>some text &lt;br&gt;</p>
```

and applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will **result** in:

```
<p>some text <br></p>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this while keeping the node tree of the source document intact? For example my source document might contain `<p>some text &lt;br&gt;</p>` and I want `<p>some text <br></p>` but if I use `xsl:text` or `xsl:value-of` I end up stripping the p tags off

Comment: @user1770475 I believe it's possible if you apply the *identity transform* template + a specific template matching text nodes, that would output the value with output escaping disabled.

Comment: @user1770475 See the example I have added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k that looks exactly like what I want, but I'm having trouble  applying the identity template to the `copy-of` nodes. Should it be something like: 

    `<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('../xml/mydocument.xml')"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:template>`

As this doesn't seem to actually apply the templates

Comment: @user1770475 You cannot use copy. Try `<xsl:apply-templates select="document('../xml/mydocument.xml')"/>`.